# Secondary index in cloudant to aggregate multiple documents to single document

Tags: cloudant

I am trying to create a secondary index in cloudant that aggregates multiple documents into a single document. This is the scenario that I have, say I have a Cloudant database that contains person addresses and three sample documents belonging to a fictitious person John G are as follows

### document 1

```
{
    "id":"xxx",
    "Name":"John G",
    "Address Type":"H",
    "Address":" Home Address blah blah blah"
}
```

### document 2

```
{
    "id":"yyy",
    "Name":"John G",
    "Address Type":"O",
    "Address":"Office Address blah blah blah"
}
```

### document 3

```
{
    "id":"zzz",
    "Name":"John G",
    "Address Type":"V",
    "Address":"Vacation/Summer house Address blah blah blah"
}
```

I would like to create a secondary index/view on this database that aggregates these three documents belonging to John G and creates one single document that looks like below

### document

```
{
    "id":"www",
    "key":"John G",
    "value":
      {
          "Address_Home":"Home Address blah blah blah",
          "Address_Office":"Office Address blah blah blah",
          "Address_Summerhouse":"Vacation/Summer house Address blah blah blah"
      }
}
```

Please suggest how should I write the view/secondary index to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't quite achieve what you suggest as you suggest it. A view takes one document and emits data based on that document only. You can't do 'sub queries' inside a map function. There is a way to link documents in a view if you have stored the id of one in the other (think foreign key). However, I think the issue here is that you're trying to shoehorn a relational model into Cloudant, which usually is a bad idea. De-normalise instead, and store all three address records in the same document. This may seem inefficient if you come from a relational background - but Cloudant does not have joins in the traditional sense, and the atomic unit is the document.

Comment: Thank you @xpqz. I thought the same but was just curious if anyone has any trick to get the same behavior in the cloudant view as that of an RDBMS join.

Comment: Have a look at this question - I think that's as close as you can get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463036/cloudant-couchdb-architecture/41466464#41466464 Also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jj3CaODMweM&t